# Error when reading or editing Organization Not Found : 000000000000: googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission, forbidden

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, cloud

To preface, I am very new to terraform and cloud. I am, in Google Cloud Shell, trying to create a `GCP landing zone`. However, when I run `terraform plan`, I get the following error message:

> Error: Error when reading or editing Organization Not Found: 000000000000: googleapi : Error 403: The caller does not have permission, forbidden with modle cloudbuild_bootstrap.data.google_organization.org,
> on .terraform/modules/cloudbuild_bootstrap/modules/cloudbuild/main.tf line 31, in data "google_organization" "org": 31: data "google_organization" "org" {

How should I alleviate this issue? I tried to run `gcloud auth application-default login`, which tells me the following:

```
You are authorizing client libraries without access to a web browser. Please run the following command on a machine with a web browser and copy its output back here. Make sure the installed gcloud version is 372.0.0 or newer.

gcloud auth application-default login --remote-bootstrap="[Long URL here]".

Enter the output of the above command:
```

I'm not exactly sure what the output I should be pasting in the prompt area is however.

Any and all comments/tips are appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Use a service account for Terraform. Start by reading this link: https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/get-started-with-terraform

Comment: Did you try to follow the instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow as suggested by `gcloud` commands output. Besides the Cloud Shell, you would need a different laptop(office/personal) with `gcloud` installed. I use Macbook.

1. In your PC/Macbook terminal, run `gcloud auth application-default login --remote-bootstrap="....`
2. You will be prompted to open a browser and authenticate your Google Cloud e-mail. Once you are done, a code will be generated & displayed in PC/Macbook terminal.
3. Copy the code from your terminal and provide it as input for your Cloud Run command input.

When I tried for the first time, I felt this a little weird but its a one-time task and ensures the safety of your Cloud Credentials & other.